# Is padding ever added to this C structure?

Tags: c

If I define a C struct as,

```
typedef struct
{
  double data[2];
} my_struct;
```

Is there any possibility that padding would be added to such a structure? Or can I safely assume that sizeof(my_struct) is always 2*sizeof(double) on all systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler implementations are allowed to add *any* padding in a structure between fields or after the final field.

It probably won't in this case, since you only have one data type, but there's no *guarantee* that it won't.

If you need to control implementation-specific behavior, many implementations will give you that level of control, such as with `#pragma pack`, for example.

Even if you *don't* have that level of control, you can use standard features to at least *catch* the problem at compile time (C11 or better):

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
typedef struct { double data[2]; } my_struct;
static_assert(sizeof(my_struct) == sizeof(double) * 2, "I do not like padding");
```